# How to create a Pub/Sub topic and send a message to its triggering Pub/Sub topic?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a GCP cloud backend where I have v2 cloud functions written in Nodejs.
I want to write a cloud function that will create a Pub/Sub push subscription
topic and send a message to a cloud function api endpoint.

I have been looking through GCP documentations to implement a cloud function to create a Pub/Sub push subscription but haven't found proper documentation for such implementation

Comment: When you say you want to create a "subscription topic," what do you mean? Topics and subscriptions are separate entities in Pub/Sub.

Comment: I want to create Pub/Sub push subscription.

Comment: What's your blocker? What did you try, in which language, what's your error?